# Peak effect of edible marijuana 11 hours after ingestion; how is it possible?1

Tags: marijuana, edible

The chocolates I've been having currently typically take about 5 hours to peak, and the last time I used them, it was literally 11 HOURS later. I ate one dose of about 4mg (I think... I lost the label but it was from a dispensary). I am sure I did not eat any other edibles in between. There's also the factor that I now drink moderate alcohol throughout the high. But can alcohol really cause the high to be so much more delayed/prolonged? Or is it something else?

It's also very high percentage THC and almost no CBD if I remember correctly.

P.S. The amount of chocolate I eat is extremely small. I usually eat literal crumbs. And this time it was a solid 1/4th chunk of a chocolate square, but still very small. So right now my working hypothesis is that there's so much dosage in so little food that there's a high amount of randomness in how it passes through my body? Or maybe part of it got stuck on my throat for a long time?

Comment: Are we speaking of chocolate or marihuana? I don’t understand that type of slang...

Comment: @Narusan-sedated Both. "Edibles" are edible items (typically chocolate candies) infused with marijuana derivatives.

Comment: Although your question isn't off topic, I think you'll find more expertise on this question in marijuana forums. Western medicine mostly knows next to nothing about marijuana because it's been prohibited from research for decades.

Comment: When eating the effects just are to some effect more unpredictable. Before reaching the brain it passes through the liver, alcohol interferes with the liver process and the brain effects. Even the exact same dose might give different results each time. Most importantly: aside from set and setting, your dosage stated seems very inaccurate. And if 'no other edibles' excludes normal foods then any timing bets are off anyway. If you edit you Q to include such info there might be even more to add.

Comment: I did eat normal food in between, but based on other users' reactions I don't think this should affect it that much. I also drank alcohol throughout, so maybe my liver was too busy processing the alcohol. I do remember a nugget of wisdom from my health class that the liver processes alcohol before everything else, so maybe the constant intake of alcohol prevented it from metabolizing the marijuana until much much later.

Comment: @CareyGregory for the record, there's plenty of ongoing research on cannabinoids. You don't need the whole plant to learn about the pharmacology. A fact which probably makes things easier. As far as this question  goes there are too many unknowns. Look up gastric emptying understand variation in digested foods in general, including THC uptake. You're uncertain of the composition of the cannabinoids, and what it was mixed with, so we have little to go with. What your BAC reached could effect Tmax, b/c it could affect liver processing. Seems like it is seeking personal medical advice.

Comment: @AtlLED Research on legal cannabinoids is extremely limited research since most of them are illegal. I stand by my statement that medicine knows next to nothing about marijuana.